# useFormik best practices

Tags: formik

The formik documentation seems to discourage use of the useFormik hook - but the entire Getting Started tutorial exclusively uses useFormik - so I'm not sure how to proceed - it's very confusing.  Is there a downside of using useFormik if I don't need connect, FastField, ErrorMessage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it discourages you to use `useFormik`, but in most of the use cases it's not necessary, as you won't get any perks of using context api. `Field`, `FieldArray`, etc uses formik context internally so you won't be able to use these components. But in my opinion by using this `useFormik` hook you'll be creating more of your own implementation for these kind of components. But it doesn't hurt to learn that as well as internals of `Formik` are based on this hook.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Ali.  But here's what the documentation says about useFormik - so, I read it as saying that it's discouraged. So why is it used as the main example in the Getting Started tutorial.  

**useFormik() is a custom React hook that will return all Formik state and helpers directly. Despite it's name, it is not meant for the majority of usecases.

Use cases for useFormik()
-  You are Jared
-  You are modifying the returned value and creating a modified version of <Formik> for your own consumption
-  You want to avoid using React Context (possibly for perf reasons)**

Comment: Yes exactly. Maybe author of that course wanted people to learn `useFormik` as well.